# How do I share one ADSL router between two different bandwidth accounts?

Tags: networking, adsl, adsl-router

My previous housemate configured his ADSL router so that we both shared the line, but connected to our own bandwidth accounts. Our login details were tied to our network connections on individual machines, and not stored on the router as seems to be the default.

I am now living elsewhere and would like to do the same thing again. We have a Billion 400G modem/router, and we need one Ubuntu machine, using one bandwidth account, and one Windows machine using another bandwidth account, to share the physical line.

My question has three parts:

1. What configuration option do I need to change on the router? I'm
   asking for general terminology here, not Billion specific step by
   step instructions, although the latter would be great.
2. What do I need to set up on the Windows machine? I know it's like a
   dial-up connection, but some clarity would be nice.
3. What would the equivalent connection be called on Ubuntu, and where would we find and set this up?

We will both connect to the router over wifi, not cable, but I don't think that is too germain.

Comment: What are "bandwidth accounts"? That's weird/nonstandard terminology, AFAIK. Do you mean to say bandwidth quota? Did they track, log, throttle, or prioritize bandwidth? And- Umm... Why aren't you asking the roommate?

Comment: OK, here we have separate line rental from bandwidth (adsl login account) accounts. As long as the line is up, we want two different adsl 'connections' running over the line. The roommate doesn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The accounts are likely PPPoE.  If you can [configure PPPoE on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE), [Windows7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcuI8wCEbCw) or [OS X](http://dialup.pacbell.net/mac_osx/index.html) use the DSL router as a media converter for the ethernet connections from the computers (bridge the network).  Or plugin in a wireless router (like an [AirPort](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1871)) and have a whole network available.

Comment: The adsl router is also a wireless AP, but that servers only to make the adls available to both PPPoE accounts.

Comment: I lost you.  I don't understand how the DSL router having an AP serves to offer PPPoE to two accounts.  If you configured the DSL router as a media converter, you will need to attach a switch to it unless it has multiple ports.  Once the switch is attached you can each add your own router/AP with your PPPoE login, or have computers connect directly through the switch and manage the PPPoE connection themselves.  Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: The AP connects two client machines to the router. It has nothing to do with the issue though, they could connect via cable, to the 4 port 'switch' built into the router. Thanks, trying it out tonight.